# Is this an extraneous solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Does
$$\sqrt{2x} = \sqrt{5x+3}$$
have an extraneous solution which is $-1$ or is the solution $-1$ ?
As I solved, both sides become $\sqrt{-2}$ but negative numbers can't be in the square root.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, we would say this is an extraneous solution.  Indeed, if we look at the domains of our functions beforehand, you ought've noticed that

$$\sqrt{2x}\implies x\ge0$$

$$\sqrt{5x+3}\implies x\ge-\frac35$$

Combined, we can only have $x\ge0$, so $x=-1$ is not a solution here.

Answer (score -1):

You can sketch two graphs $y=\sqrt{2x}$ and $y=\sqrt{5x+3}$, and realize that there is no intersection point. So there is no solution.